# Table Format From Excel To Gridview ? In Asp.Net?

Tags: asp.net

In web application [asp.net], i am trying to get the excel data in gridview. It is working fine, but the format of the table in gridview is different from the excel. I mean format of the table is different from excel to gridivew. I am placing the screen shot please find them First is Excel Format : [image]

second one is Gridview Screent shot which is in .aspx page.

[image]

Please help me for formating the table design. Thank you.

Comment: It would help us if you show the markup for your Gridview and describe which changes you want exactly. Now, we have to figure it out ourselfs by comparing screenshots.

Comment: What do you mean by format? just appearence? It is asp.net application can't you do that with CSS?

Comment: I think that you ask too much from the grid control. You ask from the grid control to be come excel - but excel is a too many years developing program, grid control is just a basic helper control for asp.net. I think that you have a lot of work to do.

Comment: Wouter De kort, i just take a gridview, with autogenerate columns is true, like this :    <asp:GridView ID="grdMygrd" runat ="server" ></asp:GridView>

Answer (score 0):

Try from this link: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=138
In one video of learning Linq I saw this tag but not remember this perfectly. But I test this, also you can make table with your linq code.
Have good time!

Answer (score 0):

One of the main visible problem is your Excel spreadsheet has sub tables (for example, Cargo Qty). In 'pure' html, this can be done using [COLSPAN or ROWSPAN](http://www.activejump.com/j-6.shtml), but with the GridView, it's not that easy, unless you create sub gridviews, like this:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ...>
  <Columns>
    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="MyHeader" DataField="MyField1"... />
    ...
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="MySubGridHeader">
      <asp:GridView runat="server" ...> // need to databind this
        <Columns>
          <asp:BoundField HeaderText="MySubHeader1" DataField="MyField2"... />
          <asp:BoundField HeaderText="MySubHeader2" DataField="MyField3"... />
        </Columns>
      </asp:GridView>
    </asp:TemplateField>
  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Otherwise I suggest you go for commercial packages which can display advanced grids, such as this one for example: [SPREAD](http://www.fpoint.com/netproducts/spreadweb/spread.aspx) (note: I'm not affiliated and I have not tested it).